# Symfony2 creating custom AccountStatusException

Tags: php, symfony

I would like to change the default Symfony logic of how users are checked before authentication using `UserChecker` class.

It has a method `checkPreAuth`, which does some checks before user is authenticated:

```
public function checkPreAuth(UserInterface $user)
{
    if (!$user instanceof AdvancedUserInterface) {
        return;
    }

    if (!$user->isAccountNonLocked()) {
        $ex = new LockedException('User account is locked.');
        $ex->setUser($user);
        throw $ex;
    }

    if (!$user->isEnabled()) {
        $ex = new DisabledException('User account is disabled.');
        $ex->setUser($user);
        throw $ex;
    }

    if (!$user->isAccountNonExpired()) {
        $ex = new AccountExpiredException('User account has expired.');
        $ex->setUser($user);
        throw $ex;
    }
}
```

I wanted to replace default `LockedException` with my own `BannedException`, because my User entity contains some extra properties such as `bannedUntil` and `banReason`, so if authorization fails, user can see the date of ban expiration and the reason of locking.

I've created the new exception for this:

```
namespace Eugenics\SiteBundle\Exception;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccountStatusException;

/**
 * Class BannedException.
 */
class BannedException extends AccountStatusException
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getMessageKey()
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $bannedUntil = $user->getBannedUntil()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $banReason = $user->getBanReason();

        return 'You are banned until ' . $bannedUntil . '. Reason: ' . $banReason;
    }
}
```

The problem is that inherited method `getUser()` doesn't get the full copy of User entity, it's just filled by standard `AdvancedUserInterface` properties like username, password etc, but not `bannedUntil` and `banReason`, they are empty.

Eventually what I see is

> "You are banned until . Reason: ".

Here is the dump of `$user` variable from the inside of `getMessageKey` method:

```
object(stdClass)#634 (28) { ["__CLASS__"]=> string(30) "Eugenics\SiteBundle\Entity\User" ["comments"]=> NULL ["id"]=> int(5) ["username"]=> string(8) "eugenics" ["email"]=> string(21) "email@example.com" ["salt"]=> string(31) "9lcjfix8eyw4scg0gkk000k4socgcoo" ["password"]=> string(60) "$2y$12$9lcjfix8eyw4scg0gkk00u79ox.0Uc.XtusBoeDFTgRUvKMi9J/FO" ["plainPassword"]=> NULL ["registeredAt"]=> NULL ["lastLoginAt"]=> NULL ["confirmationToken"]=> NULL ["passwordRequestedAt"]=> NULL ["banned"]=> bool(true) ["bannedUntil"]=> NULL ["bannedBy"]=> NULL ["banReason"]=> NULL ["firstName"]=> NULL ["lastName"]=> NULL ["birthdate"]=> NULL ["gender"]=> NULL ["photoUrl"]=> NULL ["photoPreviewUrl"]=> NULL ["confirmed"]=> NULL ["status"]=> NULL ["rating"]=> NULL ["private"]=> NULL ["lastActivityAt"]=> NULL }
```

But when I dump `$user` object directly from the `checkPreAuth()` it shows that all properties are filled properly.

Is it even possible to reach needed functionality by this way? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't the ->format() throw an Null exception? If $user->getBannedUtil() returns null then the format would throw an exception.

Comment: It does, both getBannedUntil() and getBanReason() return null, but if I call them from the checkPreAuth() it works perfectly. I don't get why getUser() doesn't return full User object when called from AccountStatusException.

Comment: The interesting thing is that dumping $ex->getUser() from checkPreAuth() shows fully filled User object, but doing the same with $this->getUser() from AccountStatusException does not.